# Now that the Quests API is deprecated, is there still a reason to use the Events API?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm having trouble understanding what the point of the Events API is in a Google Play Game Service. I understand that it can be used to create quests, but the quests API is now deprecated. If the only point of events were to create quests, why isn't the events API deprecated now?

Is there a reason to use the Events API? From what I can tell, even if I create evens, users have no ideas what events there are. I would like users to be able to see how many entities they have killed. There are intents for achievements and leaderboards, but none for events. What can I use the events API for?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the events API to track user clicks.  If a user clicks the 1 player button, an event is submitted to my "1 player event".  If a user clicks the 2 player button, an event is submitted to my "2 player event".  I do this for several key features in the app.  It allows me to see what buttons are, or are not, being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

User can still use events to keep track of score or entities defeated. The action to trigger when the event passes a threshold must be handled in code and not in a quest as before.